# Zend Framework: How can i set name attribute of an element

Tags: php, zend-framework

1- How can I set 'name' attribute of 'form' html tag in Zend Form.

2- How can I set 'name' (not 'value' attribute) attribute of an element  in Zend Form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are wanting to do this for the purpose of accessing the form with javascript, you really should use `id` (which is already there) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1- How can I set 'name' attribute of 'form' html tag in Zend Form.

`$form->setAttrib('name', 'myForm');`

#### 2- How can I set 'name' (not 'value' attribute) attribute of an element in Zend Form.

`$elt->setName('myElement');`

Comment: By adding following: $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setValue('Login');
        $submit->setAttribs(array('id' => 'btnlogin'));
        $submit->setName('mySubmit');   is generating this code : <input type="submit" name="mySubmit" id="btnlogin" value="mySubmit"> . What is wrong with the code that it is not showing value ?

Comment: `$submit->setLabel('Login')` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

In ZF1, you can call setName on the form.  Which sets both the name and id of the form.

```
    <?php
    // Your form definition
    $form->setName('blahForm');
    echo $form->setView(new Zend_View);
    ?>
```

Outputs:

```
    <form id="blahForm" name="blahForm">...</form>
```